# Why does DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff") throw FormatException?

Tags: c#, datetime, formatexception

I'm having a similar problem with FormatException being thrown. My code is simply:

```
void Orders_OnSubmit()
{
   DateTime CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
   rtbAdd( "Submitted on " + CurrentTime.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " at " + CurrentTime.TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff") );
}

void rtbAdd(String S)
{
   DefaultDelegate del = delegate()
   {
      rtb.AppendText(S + "\n");
   };
   this.Invoke(del);
}
```

What's wrong here? Is this a threading issue?

Comment: where is the exception being thrown?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's no need to explicitly access the Date and TimeOfDay properties of the DateTime instance. You can simplify your code like so:

```
rtbAdd(String.Format("Submitted on {0:MM/dd/yyyy} at {0:HH:mm:ss.ffffff}", DateTime.Now));
```

Comment: Excellent. Took me two hours of reading on MSDN and pulling my hair out after testing a few permutations in code which got me nowhere, and only a few minutes of your expert time! Thanks again.

Answer (score 34):

`TimeOfDay` is of type `TimeSpan` and it has different [formatting options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) than `DateTime`. You also need to escape the colon (`:`)

```
 currentTime.TimeOfDay.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.ffffff")
```

Your sample tried to use the `"HH"` format which is [defined for `DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#HH_Specifier), but not for `TimeSpan`.

Comment: @user1935160: There's no need to separate the time of day from your DateTime instance. Just use `CurrentTime.ToString("HH:MM:ss.ffffff")`. The same goes for the Date portion.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and helpful response!

Comment: And for anyone looking for a custom option to output  something as trivial as 11:00 PM this custom code was the only way I found to do it: https://newbedev.com/how-to-convert-24-hour-format-timespan-to-12-hour-format-timespan